# json parsing response in php

Tags: php, json, api, parsing

I am getting NULL for all my JSON data
here is my code

```
$jsons1 = file_get_contents($api_url); // returns JSON
        $jsons=json_decode($jsons1);

        foreach ($jsons as $json)
        {
        echo "\n";
        echo "<ul>";
        echo "<li>";
        echo "\nTitle : ".$json->title."\n";
        echo "\nContent: ".$json->content."\n";
        echo "</li>";
        echo "</ul>";
        }
```

I am unable to fetch it like $json->title, Am i missing something?

The output is

```
 - Title : Content:
```

Please help in this regard

here is output of `$jsons1` variable

```
{"results":[{"title": "Temp, Russia - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia","kwic": "Coordinates : 52Â°03â€²N 39Â°44â€²E ï»¿ / ï»¿ 52.05Â°N 39.733Â°E ï»¿ / 52.05; 39.733  tenmp ( Russian : Ð£ÑÐ¼Ð°Ð½ÑŒ ) is a town and the administrative center of ...","content": "","url": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/sdfds,_Russia","iurl": "","domain": "en.wikipedia.org","author": "","news": false,"votes": "1","date": 1357744155518,"related":[]}],"query": "tenp","suggestions":[],"count":96,"start":1,"length":10,"time": "412"}
```

Comment: post the json string to ur question.

Comment: Also, `print_r` your `$jsons` variable to see if you're getting the array you think you're getting.

Comment: @Kryten I am getting response, and i believe it json_decode will work

Comment: Meh, it is lame to call decoded objects as `$jsons` or `$json`. Anything that is named as JSON is supposed to be a JSON string. All decoded stuff is objects.

Comment: @user1765876 - I wasn't asking if `json_decode` will work, I was suggesting you use `print_r` to see the structure of your object. I did a quick check of the JSON document you posted, and from the structure of the decoded object, it's clear you're referring to the wrong property in your `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have object results containing your datas..

So you have just to fix your Foreach statement ..>

```
    foreach ($jsons->results as $json) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try as

```
$j = '{"results":[{"title": "Temp, Russia - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia","kwic": "Coordinates : 52Â°03â€²N 39Â°44â€²E ï»¿ / ï»¿ 52.05Â°N 39.733Â°E ï»¿ / 52.05; 39.733  tenmp ( Russian : Ð£ÑÐ¼Ð°Ð½ÑŒ ) is a town and the administrative center of ...","content": "","url": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/sdfds,_Russia","iurl": "","domain": "en.wikipedia.org","author": "","news": false,"votes": "1","date": 1357744155518,"related":[]}],"query": "tenp","suggestions":[],"count":96,"start":1,"length":10,"time": "412"}';

$data = json_decode($j,true);

foreach ($data["results"] as $key=>$val){
    echo "\n";
    echo "<ul>";
    echo "<li>";
    echo "\nTitle : ".$val["title"]."\n";
    echo "\nContent: ".$val["content"]."\n";
    echo "</li>";
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Right now there is only one data in **results** element so looping is better if there are more.